# Intuition behind : If rank of a matrix is $r$ then it has a maximum of $r$ non zero eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, intuition, matrix-rank

One of my peers just said me that :

"If rank of a matrix is $r$ then it has a maximum of $r$ non zero eigen values".

When I asked him how did he arrive at it, he said that he used ***rank-nullity theorem***. I do not like rigorous mathematics without understanding the intuition behind the same.

Intuitively what I know is that (with out hardcore definitions):

If we have an $n\times n$ matrix of rank $r$, then the matrix can be reduced to a form [row reduced echelon form] where we have $r$ pivot columns and $n-r$ free columns.

[image: diagram]

The diagram above is based on what I have learned from MIT 18.06 Gilbert Strang's lectures. So the $n\times n$ matrix having rank $r$, has a null space having $n-r$ vectors in its basis. So this is what I guess the rank-nullity theorem has to say: rank of the matrix ($r$)+ number of vectors in the basis of the null space ($n-r$) equals $n$. [Corresponding to the equation $AX=O_{n\times 1}$]

Now what I can understand is that, if zero is the eigen value of a matrix $A$, then the equation,

$$AX=\lambda X$$

Turns out to be

$$AX=O_{n\times 1}$$

and we get an equation similar to that while finding the null space of a matrix. But now how to arrive at the required fact intuitively?

Comment: Null space is the same as the eignespace of eigenvalue zero. Since eigenvalues can either be zero or nonzero,  the rank is the max number of distinct eigenvalues (each dimension has exactly one eigenvalue associated to it, not necessarily distinct or even leading to an eigenvector)

Comment: @TheoBendit sorry, it was a typo...

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Intuitive proofs are great for learning, but they're very specific from person to person. What one person finds intuitive can wildly differ from what another person finds intuitive. What is your *intuitive* understanding of rank? What does a matrix having $r$ non-zero eignevalues mean to you?

Comment: for me, rank of a matrix, means (intuitively) the number of independent rows or columns in the matrix. Hmm a matrix having r non zero eigen value for me, means that, for each of the non zero eigen value, we shall get vectors $X$ such that multiplying $X$ from left by $A$, gives a vector in the same direction (parallel) as that of $X$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I did not quite get the picture which you tried to explain. Could please elaborate or suggest me a video lecture explaining the same?

Comment: Maybe this won't be the intuition you're asking for, but it seems to me like this comes down to the following result: Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix, and let $v_1,..,v_k$ be nonzero eigenvectors for the distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$ of $A$ respectively. Then $\{v_1,...,v_k \}$ are independent. Moreover each $v_j$ is in the column space of $A$. Finally, $rank(A) = \dim(Col(A)) \geq k$. So $rank(A) \geq |\{\lambda \in K \setminus \{0 \} : \exists v \in K^n \setminus \{0 \} . Av = \lambda v \}|$.

Answer (score 1):

Given your intuitive understanding in the comments, I think I have an answer for you.

Think about the process of multiplying a vector $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)^\top$ to a matrix $A$, consisting of columns $v_1, \ldots, v_n$. If you do a bit of calculation, you can see that
$$Ax = x_1 v_1 + \ldots + x_n v_n.$$
That is to say, you obtain a linear combination of the columns of $A$, with the entries of $x$ being your coefficients.

So, if we have $x$, an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $0$, then this corresponds to a non-trivial linear combination of the columns of $A$ that produces the $0$ vector. The existence of such a combination is equivalent to the columns of $A$ not being linearly independent, and thus having deficient (column) rank.

If your matrix has rank $r < n$, then it means that we can pick out $n - r$ vectors, and express them as linear combinations of the previous vectors in the order $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, until the columns become linearly independent. For example, $x_i$ would be one such vector if there exist $a_1, \ldots, a_{i - 1}$ such that
$$v_i = a_1 v_1 + \ldots + a_{i - 1} v_{i - 1}.$$
We can then rearrange this to form a $0$-linear combination:
$$a_1 v_1 + \ldots + a_{i - 1} v_{i - 1} + (-1)v_i = 0.$$
This produces an eigenvector $x = (a_1, \ldots, a_{i - 1}, -1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0)^\top$ for $A$, corresponding to $0$. We can repeat this process for each of the $n - r$ vectors that we can removed from the columns so that the remainder are linearly independent. This produces $n - r$ eigenvectors corresponding to $0$.

Furthermore, these eigenvectors are linearly independent. Note that the eigenvectors formed by the above process take a form similar to rows in row-echelon form: they end in a "leading" (or, I guess, "trailing") $-1$, and have $0$s below. where the $-1$ resides depends on which vector you take out (take out $v_i$, and $-1$ lies in the $i$th position). So, each such eigenvector has a different trailing $-1$, and it shouldn't be difficult to see that these vectors are linearly independent.

So, we have $n - r$ linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to $0$, and so the multiplicity of $0$ is at least $n - r$. Each $n \times n$ matrix has at most $n$ eigenvalues, so the total multiplicities of non-zero eigenvalues is at most $r$.

Comment: I got the point that corresponding to $0$ we have $n-r$ eigen vectors. But I could not get which part in the answer says the logic about multiplicity of $0$ to be $\geq n-r$. Please can you clarify this small point...

Comment: The multiplicity of $0$ is the dimension of the generalised eigenspace corresponding to $0$, which is a superspace of the eigenspace corresponding to $0$ (if the matrix is diagonalisable, they are the same thing). By finding $n - r$ linearly independent eigenvectors, this guarantees the eigenspace is of dimension $n - r$, and hence the same can be said of the generalised eigenspace. That is, the multiplicity is at least $n - r$. Basically: at least $k$ linearly independent eigenvectors implies multiplicity is at least $k$.